# How do I sum a certain value for certain day of the week?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame of phone calls that contains timestamp and duration of the call. How would I sum the total duration for each day for all phone calls? The timestamp is a string so I am having trouble parsing it to an actual date. I'm not sure if spark has any support for timestamps.

DataFrame table

```
  timestamp   |  duration
1414592818364 |   210
1414575535061 |   110
1411328461890 |   140
1434606396339 |   90
```

Comment: Any supported language or only Java? Example input as always welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UDF to parse timestamps. Below you can find a Python solution but it should pretty easy to do the same thing using another supported language:

With raw SQL:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    {'timestamp': 1414592818364, 'duration': 210},
    {'timestamp': 1414575535061, 'duration': 110},
    {'timestamp': 1411328461890, 'duration': 140},
    {'timestamp': 1434606396339, 'duration': 90}]))


def parse_timestamp(tm):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(tm / 1000)
    return '{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)

sqlContext.registerFunction('parse_timestamp', parse_timestamp)

df.registerTempTable('df')

query = '''
    SELECT parse_timestamp(timestamp) AS date, sum(duration) AS total_durtaion
    FROM df GROUP BY parse_timestamp(timestamp)'''

(sqlContext
    .sql(query)
    .show())
```

or SQL DSL:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

(df
    .withColumn('date', udf(parse_timestamp, StringType())(df.timestamp))
    .select('date', 'duration')
    .groupby('date')
    .sum()
    .show())
```

**EDIT**:

Since Spark 1.5 there is no need for a custom udf.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, col, sum

(df
  .groupBy(from_unixtime(df.timestamp / 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("date"))
  .agg(sum(col("duration"))))
```

Comment: Will this be faster than creating PairRDD and summing the value? For example, I can get day as a integer representation and set that as the key for my pair and the value will be the duration. Then I just aggregate all the keys and sum up the values. Which way would you say its faster in terms of parallelism?

Comment: If you believe [in benchmarks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html) then data frame operations should be significantly faster than using low level interface. Personally I don't have enough experience to answer this question.